# Flash clips in Android WebView overlapping issue

Tags: android, flash, webview, overlapping

The problem I am about to describe is probably already referred to indirectly in many posts (so I can see), however I don't seem to find the answer I look for.

Here's what I have:

An android view with native UI components at the top of the screen, and a webview covering the rest of the screen.

The webView displays a web page containing Flash clips.

When I scroll the webpage it seems that the flash clips are separate from the WebView spanning beyond the boundaries of the hosting WebView. They actually overlap with the native UI controls (cover them).

How can I prevent this from happening?

Thanks for an experienced advice.

Comment: Im not well versed in Android, but I know that using WMode transparent when embedding flash in html can cause issues, could be one to check if you are embedding them in html and then showing in the Android browser

Comment: Well I'm not much into Flash developing, but as far as embedding into HTML goes, any content should be bound inside the page. So I was wondering if this Android issue has a workaround?

Answer (score 1):

Override addView in WebView.java to change the zorder of surfaceview/flash; 
File: webkit/WebView.java

```
 @Override
    public void addView(View child, int index) {
        if (child.getClass().getName().equals("com.adobe.flashplayer.FlashPaintSurface")) 
        {
              ((SurfaceView) child).setZOrderOnTop(false);
        }
        super.addView(child, index);
     }
```

Comment: Thank you. This helped me to resolve an issue on android 2.3, when embedded youtube video would overlap with tabs and other controls and stay on screen after a tab was changed.